# CPTBarPlot - barTip and barBase properties

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart, core-plot

I'm trying to use the barTip and barBase properties for a CPTBarPlot to create the impression that bars that sticks on top and expand to the bottom.

Basically I'm thinking that overriding func number(for plot: CPTPlot, field fieldEnum: UInt, record idx: UInt) -> Any? and setting the right barBase I will achieve that.

Does anyone know if there should be a correlation between barTip and barBase? (e.g. barBase + barTip = max value)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `baseValue` for the bar plot to the top of the `yRange` instead of the bottom. You can use a negative length for plot ranges to reverse the direction. For example, set the `location` of the range to 5 and `length` to -5 to make a range between 5 and zero (0).